# Search String in Char Array in IOS xcode program?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Char info[256]="Apple,iPhone,iPad";

I want to search in this char array, for example, search "iPhone" in the above array, 
Return TRUE since it contains this string.

How to do that in iOS xcode program? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
BOOL stringInString(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    return (strstr(s1, s2) != NULL);
}
```